# Show that $ trace(AB) = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i})^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, trace

With $a,b \in \mathbb{K}^n, \ A:=(a_{i}a_{j})_{i,j = 1,...,n} \in \mathbb{K}^{n x n} $ and $ B:=(b_{i}b_{j})_{i,j = 1,...,n} \in \mathbb{K}^{n x n} $ (where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field)
I want to show that

$$ trace(AB) = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i})^2 $$

I am fairly new to matrices and especially traces, so any hint as to where I begin here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There’s a formula for the multiplication and a formula for the trace...

Comment: Also, if I’m reading your matrices right, shouldn’t the square be on the inside?  That, or it’s just wrong.

Comment: Maybe that is a mistake in my textbook, there it is stated with the square outside the bracket.

Comment: Well I cannot get it to work even for diagonal matrices.  Maybe someone else can chime in on what’s going on here.

Comment: @Randall These are very special matrices since the $(i,j)$ entry is the product $a_ia_j$ or $b_ib_j$. These cannot be diagonal unless they are the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(i,i)$-entry of $AB$ is given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^n A_{i,k}B_{k,i} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_ia_kb_kb_i = a_ib_i \sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k.$$
Thus the the trace of $AB$ is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left( a_ib_i \sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k \right).$$
Can you show that is equal to $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right)^2$?

Comment: Ah i see now. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, it wasn’t my question anyway but I still appreciate learning something.

Comment: Can I write: $\left( \sum_{i=1}^n  a_ib_i \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k \right) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right)^2$ per associativity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "per associativity," but yes you can write that.