# Prove that for square matrices $tr(A\times B)=tr(A)tr(B).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that for square matrices $ A\,(m\times m) $ and $ B\,(n\times n) $, $tr(A\times B)=tr(A)tr(B).$

$tr(A)=\sum_{i=1}^ma_{ii}=a_{11}+a_{22}+...+a_{mm}$

$tr(B)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ii}=b_{11}+b_{22}+...+b_{nn}$

Since $A\times B$ has to be true, the matrices have to be the same size and $m=n$.

$A\times B=\sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik}b_{kj}=a_{i1}b_{1j}+...+a_{nm}b_{mn}$

I don't know if what I've done is correct so far and I'm not sure how to go on with solving the trace of $A\times B$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2569460/8581)

Comment: The statement is false.

Comment: Are you considering [*Kronecker product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)? Then $\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes B)=(\operatorname{tr}A)(\operatorname{tr}B)$ is true for square matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Your notation is not standard. Please clarify if by $\times$ you mean the Kronecker product or the standard matrix product.

Comment: Hi! I am sorry for the unclear presentation. By $\times$ I mean the Kronecker product. Thank you to all who have taken time to help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is $m\times m$ with typical elements $A_{ij}$ and $B$ is $n\times n$ with typical elements $B_{hk}$. We have
$$
A\otimes B=\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11}B & A_{12}B & \cdots & A_{1m}B\\
A_{21}B & A_{22}B & \cdots & A_{2m}B \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{m1}B & A_{m2}B & \cdots & A_{mm}B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the diagonal elements of $A\otimes B$ are 
$$
A_{11}B_{11},\ldots,A_{11}B_{nn},A_{22}B_{11},\ldots,A_{22}B_{nn},\ldots,A_{mm}B_{11},\ldots,A_{mm}B_{nn}.
$$
Summing these yields
\begin{align*}
&\quad\operatorname{Tr}(A\otimes B)\\
&=A_{11}B_{11}+\cdots+A_{11}B_{nn}+A_{22}B_{11}+\cdots+A_{22}B_{nn}+\cdots+A_{mm}B_{11}+\cdots+A_{mm}B_{nn}\\
&=A_{11}(B_{11}+\cdots+B_{nn})+A_{22}(B_{11}+\cdots+B_{nn})+\cdots+A_{mm}(B_{11}+\cdots+B_{nn})\\
&=(A_{11}+\cdots+A_{mm})(B_{11}+\cdots+B_{nn})=\operatorname{Tr}(A)\operatorname{Tr}(B).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

If you meant $\operatorname{tr}(A\times B)$ as $\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes B)$ then as @[Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee) mentioned, we have:

$\displaystyle {\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}}\otimes {\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}a\cdot {\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}}&b\cdot {\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}}\\c\cdot {\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}}&d\cdot {\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}}\\\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}a\cdot p&a\cdot q&b\cdot p&b\cdot q\\a\cdot r&a\cdot s&b\cdot r&b\cdot s\\c\cdot p&c\cdot q&d\cdot p&d\cdot q\\c\cdot r&c\cdot s&d\cdot r&d\cdot s\\\end{bmatrix}}$

So we have:

$$(\operatorname{tr}A)(\operatorname{tr}B)=(a+d)(p+s)=a\cdot p+a \cdot s+d\cdot p+d\cdot s=\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes B)$$

Where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and $\operatorname{tr}(.)$ is the trace of a matrix.

---

If you meant $\operatorname{tr}(A\times B)$ as $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$, which is a simple [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), then :

$\displaystyle {\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\\end{bmatrix}} {\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}ap+br&aq+bs\\cp+dr&cq+ds\\\end{bmatrix}}$

So now we can see that:

$$(\operatorname{tr}A)(\operatorname{tr}B)=(a+d)(p+s)=a\cdot p+a \cdot s+d\cdot p+d\cdot s \ne a\cdot p+b\cdot r+c\cdot q+d\cdot s=\operatorname{tr}(AB)$$

You can follow the same methodology and it would be true for any $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: What about cases beyond the $2\times 2$ one?

Comment: @anomaly the calculations are perfectly the same

Comment: @anomaly As ricardo said, the calculations are exactly the same. Moreover, I personally feel that this kind of small matrix products will help develop intuitions required to generalise the method. I also feel that it might look a bit "cluttered" when you try to generalise something with dots ($\cdot \cdot \cdot$) and $n^{th}$ terms. It's just my way of thinking though :)

Comment: @paulplusx: The solution to that is using better notation (e.g., yurnero's solution below), not grinding through the details of a particular case.

Comment: @anomaly Well, you are correct and your argument applies to all such generalization perfectly but I feel that if there is another method (shouldn't call it a method) of "understanding" it by using simple examples (similar to induction) and then generalizing it intuitively, sometimes it helps a lot, much better than notations(at least for me). I do accept that yurnero's solution is perfect for this question (because it literally answers it to the point).